# Insert DataTable rows to DataBaseTables using DataAdapter: leave out one column in DataTable

Tags: sqldataadapter

i have DataTable named dtPurchaseProduct
that has columns

- dtcolPurchaseProduct_No
- dtcolnInvoiceNo
- dtcolnProductNo
- dtcolnProductName
- dtcolnQuantity
- dtcolnPrice

these are bound to datagridview **except *dtcolnProductNo*** because only product names are required to be seen

and i have DatabaseTable Named PurchaseProduct
that has columns

- PurchaseProduct_No
- InvoiceNo
- ProductNo
- Quantity
- Price

now after allowing user to add/update/delete the DataTable rows through textboxes
i want to insert these rows to DataBaseTable with **DataAdapter**

Is it possible to do that? i don't have select command and even the columns are not exactly the same that is i don't have database column for  **dtlcolnProductName**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string qry = "select * from PurchaseProduct where 0 = 1";
        sa = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, conn);
        dataSet = new DataSet();
        sa.Fill(dataSet);
        dataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Add("dtcolnPurchaseProductProductName",typeof(string));
```